# how to disabled button drop to bottom in responsive table bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z83R5.png)
my buttons always drop to bottom on a smaller screen

I have tried styling `<td>` with `width: 300px` but it still doesn't work

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table ">
            <tr class="bg-black text-light">
                <th>NO</th>
                <th>NAMA</th>
                <th>NIS</th>
                <th>GENDER</th>
                <th>AKSI</th>
            </tr>
      @forelse ($students as $student)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->nis }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->gender }}</td>
            <td class="" style="width:300px">
                <a href=""  class="text-decoration-none ">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Lihat</button>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-decoration-none ">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>
                </a>
                <a href=""  class="text-decoration-none ">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Hapus</button>
                </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      @empty
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="bg-danger text-light"> Tidak ada data</td>
          </tr>
      @endforelse
        </table>
        </div>
```

I have tried to style the `<td>` with a `display: flex` but it causes excess spacing in the button column

Comment: Have you tried `min-width`? That way the row will not get smaller than the value but can still grow with a larger viewport.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.